# Active Dropdown Button on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slide, dropdown

I use this method to get slide down menu (find here: [Adding a slide effect to bootstrap dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115833/adding-a-slide-effect-to-bootstrap-dropdown)) and modify for use **on hover** action.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.3s, opacity 0.2s 0.1s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.3s, opacity 0.2s 0.1s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: max-height 0.3s, opacity 0.2s 0.1s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.3s, opacity 0.2s 0.1s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
    transition: max-height 0.3s, opacity 0.2s 0.1s, visibility 0s 0.3s;

    max-height: 0;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: hidden;

    min-width: 170px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.3s, opacity 0.2s, visibility 0s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.3s, opacity 0.2s, visibility 0s;
    -ms-transition: max-height 0.3s, opacity 0.2s, visibility 0s;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.3s, opacity 0.2s, visibility 0s;
    transition: max-height 0.3s, opacity 0.2s, visibility 0s;

    max-height: 250px;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

}
```

It's work great for mobile and Tab/Laptop/PC but I would like to force active Dropdown button **on hover**. A little smaple:

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvsYk.png) and [how it's look now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nubQf.png)

For this button I use this code:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, /*GALERIA button*/
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    background-color: #155670;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #87cde8;

}
```

I was trying to use this code for get effect what I would like to have:

```
.navbar-nav > li.dropdown:hover { background-color: gray ; }

.dropdown:hover { background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

It's work for add background color but this is not what I want. I want to get active Dropdown button on hover just like when you click on it.

So I was thinking about some JQ script inside in script tag. I found something [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33589800/bootstrap-dropdown-active-open-on-hover-and-link-on-click).

```
    $('.dropdown').hover(function(){ 
  $('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('click'); 
});
```

But the problem is on mobile view because **I need to click twice** to open my Dropdown button with content. I think JQ should be the best solution but I don't know how to edit it correctly (I was trying to).

Thanks for interested.